# CLLocationManager not determining location

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, core-location, cllocationmanager

I'm having some trouble getting the user's current location. I realize there are many questions on this topic, but I have read them and done exactly what the Apple documentation tells me to do and still it doesn't work.

I have the following code in my MasterViewController:

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil

var locationManager:CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "printPlace:")
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
    if let split = self.splitViewController {
        let controllers = split.viewControllers
        self.detailViewController = controllers[controllers.count-1].topViewController as? DetailViewController
    }

    if !CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        println("location services disabled")
    }
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}


func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]) {
    println("found location")
}

@IBAction func printPlace(sender: AnyObject) {
    let currentLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = locationManager.location.coordinate
    println("\(currentLocation.latitude) , \(currentLocation.longitude)")
}
```

I also added the **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** key to my info.plist. However, when I run this code, **didUpdateLocations** is never called, and **printPlace** gives a fatal error because **locationManager.location** is nil. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you trying this on device or in the simulator?

Comment: On a device, iPhone 5 running iOS 8

Comment: Does the app ask you for permission to use your location? You might have to delete the app and reflash it to the device in order to test this.

Comment: Did you use `NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription` as you wrote or `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`? I often have this typo and forget the `Use`. Once you change it and it still doesn't work then follow the answer below

Comment: Sorry, the typo was only in the question. Will edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, the issue might be that you said you updated your .plist for **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** but in your code you call `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()` which is something different. You either need to add the proper one to the .plist (**NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription**), or request only for when in use like this: `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()`.

Also, as the comment on your original post points out, it should be **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription**, not **NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription**

Comment: Yea if you don't have the matching pair, it won't even give you an error, it just won't do anything.

Comment: That was exactly it! Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Comment: Also, as a note of good practice, if you're done with the `locationManager` after it's received the location, make sure to stop it!